# Contact Form 7 not sending emails with Mandrill

Tags: wordpress, mandrill, contact-form-7

I actually fixed the bug last night, but since I couldn't find a solution on google, I thought I'd answer it on Stackoverflow for people who will run into the same problem in the future.

Contact Form 7 was not sending out emails and throwing a red error box. Mandrill was working properly, so it had to be my wordpress configurations.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by installing an SMTP plugin (I decided to use [easy wp smtp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)). All you have to do is put in your Mandrill SMTP values and it should start working!